# ASP.NET Usermanagement Starterkit

Tags: asp.net, authentication

im searching for a asp.net starterkit which enables me to manage users and roles on my website (as a websiteadmin). I've found MyWSAT - but that's a bit too much tamtam for my purposes.
I simply need to:
create and manage users & roles ...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your post it is not exactly clear  what you are looking for in ASP.NET account management (create from scratch, extend existing functionality, manage accounts or create an administration tool).

1) To create ASP.NET user management feature to your web-site, then here is a simple and quick steps: [ASP.NET Basic user account management](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/ASP.NET/ASPNET-35-Basic-User-Account-Management/) or 
you may look at [Introduction to the Club Web Site Starter Kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479303.aspx)

2) To extend and customize build in asp.net membership [ASP.NET's Membership, Roles, and Profile](https://web.archive.org/web/20210513220018/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx)

3) To build your Own Website Administration Tool: [build your own website administration tool](https://web.archive.org/web/20210306174425/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/052307-1.aspx)

4) To understand how to Use Role Manager in ASP.NET 2.0, look at this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647401.aspx)

5) If you are looking for ASP.NET MVC alternative then here it is: [Asp.Net MVC Membership Starter Kit](https://github.com/TroyGoode/MembershipStarterKit)